# Vuetify - How to change v-img source with setTimeout function

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

I have a problem with my code:

```
<v-card class="d-flex flex-column">
<v-img id="image" src="w3schools.com/js/landscape.jpg" height="600"> <v-card-title class="headline"> 
Search for 
<v-spacer></v-spacer> 
<span class="caption font-italic font-weight-light">yes</span> 
</v-card-title> 
</v-img> 
</v-card> 

<script> 
setTimeout(function() { document.getElementById("image").setAttribute("src", "w3schools.com/js/smiley.gif"); }, 5000); </script>
```

It is not changing the image. What seems to be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not recommended to manipulate DOM as you're doing, try to create a data property called `url` and change it where you want, for example set the `setTimeout` in the created hook as follows:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data() {
    return {
      url: 'https://www.w3schools.com/js/landscape.jpg',
    }
  },
  created(){
   setTimeout(()=>{
   this.url="https://www.w3schools.com/js/smiley.gif"},5000)
  }
})
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@4.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, minimal-ui">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <v-app>
    <v-content>
      <v-container>
      <v-card class="d-flex flex-column"> <v-img id="image" :src="url" height="600"> <v-card-title class="headline"> Search for <v-spacer></v-spacer> <span class="caption font-italic font-weight-light">yes</span> </v-card-title> </v-img> </v-card>
      </v-container>
    </v-content>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! @BoussadjraBrahim; would you also be able to have a look on this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61042197/how-to-clear-v-autocomplete-dropdown-list-of-data-coming-from-api-which-is-depen

Comment: Please provide a running example like i this provided in my answer in order to debug it easily